# Fetch Previous Week Records from MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a MySql table having a lot of records. But i want to fetch seperate records of current & previous week.

Query for Current Week Records which works perfectly

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_track WHERE WEEK(`date_created`) = WEEK(CURDATE())
```

Query for Previous Week but it dosn't work

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_track WHERE WEEK(`date_created`) = WEEK(CURDATE()) INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_track 
WHERE WEEK(`date_created`) = WEEK(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
```

OR:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_track 
WHERE WEEK(`date_created`) = WEEK(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Answer (score -1):

That doesnt look like an index can be used but thats a side issue really.  You want your curdate to be - 7 days

SELECT * FROM tbl_track WHERE WEEK(`date_created`) = WEEK(ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY));